# Optimised GPU convolution for low memory integrated devices -such as arm processors /GPUs?

Tags: computer-vision, arm, opencl, convolution, mali

I wish to implement convolution on arm mali GPUs and want it to be optimised for both speed and memory ? What's the best way to do this? GEMM based MCMK convolutions are not suited as they utilise a lot of memory. Also, a direct implementation on GPU is way slower than the corresponding CPU version. Any time for memory reshaping should be taken into account for timing calculations.

Comment: Did you try fourier transform based convolution? It is many times faster than naive convolution for filter width of 20-30 or more, especially best when convolution filter has same size with the image.

Comment: Well. My primary concern is regarding computer vision applications so at max the filter width will be 7 while the common kernel width will be 3 or 5 !

Comment: See https://github.com/ARM-software/ComputeLibrary for some pre-optimized implementations.